# Thread Java Метод run() и Метод start()

Tags: java, многопоточность

**Задание**:
*Создать 2 произвольных класса с полями и методами.
Необходимо синхронизировать методы этих классов между собой, т.е. чтобы выводило на экран значения друг за другом (1 класс, 2 класс, 1, 2 и т.д.).*

Можете проверить соответствует ли мой код на заданию? Просто у заданий нет ответа. Когда вместо метода `run()` ставлю метод `start()`, компилятор выдает ошибку

Мой код:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();

        Thread thr1 = new Thread(a);
        Thread thr2 = new Thread(b);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            thr1.run();
            thr2.run();
        }
    }
}
public class A implements Runnable{

    String str2 = "Class A";

    @Override
    public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
                System.out.println(str2);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    public String getStr2() {
        return str2;
    }
}
public class B implements Runnable{

    String str1 = "Class B";

    @Override
    public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
                System.out.println(str1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    public String getStr1() {
        return str1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Во-первых само задание не слишком понятно.  Во-вторых, какую ошибку выдает компилятор? В-третьих, вы создали экземпляры потоков `Thread`, но так и не запустили отдельные потоки (для этого и нужно вызывать `start`), у вас просто в _одном потоке_ запускаются методы `run` разных классов.  Синхронизации нескольких потоков нет, она может выполняться при помощи контроля доступа к _общему_ объекту (`synchronized`) и использованию методов `wait/notify/notifyAll`  См. [туториал по синхронизации/многопоточности](https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/1994-sinkhronizacija-potokov-operator-synchronized)

Comment: IllegalThreadStateException вот такую ошибку выдает компилятор если вместо run использую start

Comment: `IllegalThreadStateException` является `RuntimeException` -- то есть это исключение выбрасывается _во время выполнения_ кода, а не на этапе компиляции.  [Метод `start` нельзя вызывать несколько раз](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start--): _It is never legal to start a thread more than once. In particular, a thread may not be restarted once it has completed execution. **Throws:**
`IllegalThreadStateException` - if the thread was already started._